# Unable to install distribution site

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

For a course I am taking, I need to install the package(?) site into an Anaconda virtual environment. I was able to install the other requirements for the course using the command

```
pip install 'somename==version'
```

However, when I ran

```
pip install 'site==0.0.1'
```

I got the error message

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement site (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for site
```

The only information about site that I can find is (https://libraries.io/pypi/site), but it does not really give much information.

I am using Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64) and Python 3.5.3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) is internal to the Python interpreter, and is used to initialize machine-specific details of your Python installation.

What's telling you that you need to install this module? Ignore it. It's wrong.

Comment: I'm taking Stanford's CS231n and trying to do the assignment (http://cs231n.github.io/assignments2017/assignment1/). It is one of the requirements (see requirements.txt in zip file).

Comment: That part of the requirements file is wrong. Ignore it.